# Kendo grid binding not working in angularjs

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to bind list which i am populating after receiving response from API. I can see the objects into the list but i still didn't understand why kendo grid is not binding datasource. i have code as below.

```
vm.getAccounts = function () {
        acctSearchService.searchAccounts(null, vm.AccountSearchModel)
            .then(getAccountsSuccess, getAccountsFailure);
    }

    vm.accountGridData = [];
    function getAccountsSuccess(response) {
        vm.accountGridData.push(response.model);
        return vm.accountGridData;
    }
```

i am getting result into `vm.accountGridData` after receiving response from API call and i am trying to bind that to datasource of kendo grid as below.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: { data: vm.accountGridData },
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: vm.mainGridColumns
    });
```

Do i need to do anything else to get the data ?

[image: screen while denuging]

Comment: where are trying to do .kendoGrid? I assume it is done in a directive rather than controller right?

Comment: this is in controller.

Comment: Ah move it to a directive, whatever is in your controller is not affected since the page is rendered already

Comment: can you give some example please, i am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: could you please share your html? @tt0206

Comment: I don't have much in html it's just div tag '<div id="grid"></div>'. Are you asking anything else or that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the way after fighting. it's in simple one step.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.silver.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <kendo-grid k-scope-field="grid" options="mainGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
        .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http){

        $scope.data = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);

        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          type:"json",
          url: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          $scope.grid.dataSource.data(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
          dataSource: {
            data: $scope.data,
            pageSize: 5
          },
          sortable: true,
          pageable: true,
           filterable: {
                    mode: "row"
                },
          resizable: true,
          columns: [{
            field: "userId",
            title: "userId",
            width: "120px"
          },{
            field: "id",
            title: "ID",
            width: "120px"
          },{
            field: "title",
            width: "120px"
          },{
            field: "body",
            width: "120px"
          }]
        };

      })
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directive like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',    
    scope: {},
    template: [].join(''),
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.getAccounts = function () {
             acctSearchService.searchAccounts(null, vm.AccountSearchModel).then(getAccountsSuccess, getAccountsFailure);
        }

        vm.accountGridData = [];
        function getAccountsSuccess(response) {
            vm.accountGridData.push(response.model);
            return vm.accountGridData;
        }
    },
    link: function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: { data: vm.accountGridData },
            height: 550,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: vm.mainGridColumns
        }); 
    }
  };
});
```

And in your html:

```
<div my-directive></div>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need data property in your datasource if you don't implement custom read function for it. 
Datasource property should be an array or kendo-datasource object.

Try this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: vm.accountGridData,
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: vm.mainGridColumns
    });
```

And checkout grid documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid

Comment: i have tried assigning arraylist to datasource the way you have suggested, but i think what  yeaer have pointed that **whatever is in your controller is not affected since the page is rendered already** and that is might be the reason its not working.

Comment: As I know grid make wrapper around your array and after initialization not refer to it. If you want to update datasource you can add `kendo-grid="grid"` directive to your grid html and later when you received data load it to `$scope.grid.datasource.read(myDataArray)` or do it with jquery if dont want to use directives

Comment: thanks @Layonez to pointing out. i have added  **$("#grid").kendoGrid({})** after inside the function where i am getting datasource and its working.

Comment: but the paging and filtering is not working as expected. even after **pageSize: 5** provided its loading all the data. that's kind of weird.